# Absolute path on Vim 'tags' option

Tags: vim, ctags

I'm facing a problem to use an absolute path on Vim 'tags' option under Windows XP.

Directory hierarchy:

```
C:/
| Temp/
| | tags
| test.cpp
```

Commands below on vim while editing test.cpp

```
:pw
  C:\

:set tags?
  tags=./tags,tags,'C:/Temp/tags','C:\Temp\tags'

:echo tagfiles()
  []

:echo findfile('tags', 'C:/Temp')
  Temp\tags
```

So, despite the tag file can be found using `findfile()`, tag information aren't available to `:tag` or `:ptag` commands, and it is not found by `tagfiles()`.

What am I missing here?

Note: I'd like to avoid using relative path and wildcards, as I'm working with a project with multi-level directory hierarchy with a single tag file, and using wildcards would be too slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `:set tags=./tags,tags,c:/Temp/tags`.

I think the problem comes from how you wrote the path to `tags`, quoted.

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem! Just curious... any idea of why removing these quotes changed the behavior?

Comment: Because that's how you are supposed to write paths in your configuration file wether you are on some UNIX variant or Windows. I suppose the goal is to make vimrc files portable. BTW, thanks to Luc Hermitte for fixing my typo.